# How to copy a child node from parent node and keep it in another parent node based on employee match?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and have a requirement of copying a child node and placing it in another node based on employee id match?

Both nodes are having EmpID and need to be copied.

Workers_Data -> LeaveStatus node (only when the EmpID matches to) wd:ChangeEventSummary->wd:ChangeEvent->wd:EventDetails and keep the entire report as it is.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<wd:Census_Report xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
<wd:Workers>
    <wd:Worker_Data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <wd:EmpID>50211</wd:EmpID>
        <wd:LeaveStatus> <!--This entire node need to copy to 
EventDetails-->
            <wd:LeaveDetail>
                <wd:LOA_Start_Date>2017-12-22</wd:LOA_Start_Date>
                <wd:LOA_End_Date>2018-01-22</wd:LOA_End_Date>
            </wd:LeaveDetail>
            <wd:LeaveDetail>
                <wd:LOA_Start_Date>2018-02-20</wd:LOA_Start_Date>
                <wd:LOA_End_Date>2018-03-02</wd:LOA_End_Date>
            </wd:LeaveDetail>
        </wd:LeaveStatus>
        <wd:Allocation_Details>
            <wd:AllocationInstance>
                <wd:Costing_ID/>
                <wd:Start_Date/>
                <wd:End_Date/>
                <wd:Costing_Allocation_Data>
                    <wd:Allocation_Order/>
                    <wd:Cost_Center_Allocation/>
                    <wd:Region_Allocation/>
                    <wd:Location_Allocation/>
                    <wd:Distribution_Percentage/>
                    <wd:Default_from_Organization_Assignment/>
                </wd:Costing_Allocation_Data>
            </wd:AllocationInstance>
        </wd:Allocation_Details>
    </wd:Worker_Data>
  </wd:Workers>
 <wd:ChangeEventSummary>       
    <wd:ChangeEvent xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <wd:EmpID>50211</wd:EmpID>
        <wd:TermDate>2018-04-27</wd:TermDate>
        <wd:EventDetails/><!--Paste the Leave Status inside this node -->
    </wd:ChangeEvent>
</wd:ChangeEventSummary>
</wd:Census_Report>
```

Expected output is as below:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <wd:Census_Report xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
 <wd:Workers>
    <wd:Worker_Data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <wd:EmpID>50211</wd:EmpID>
        <wd:LeaveStatus>
            <wd:LeaveDetail>
                <wd:LOA_Start_Date>2017-12-22</wd:LOA_Start_Date>
                <wd:LOA_End_Date>2018-01-22</wd:LOA_End_Date>
            </wd:LeaveDetail>
            <wd:LeaveDetail>
                <wd:LOA_Start_Date>2018-02-20</wd:LOA_Start_Date>
                <wd:LOA_End_Date>2018-03-02</wd:LOA_End_Date>
            </wd:LeaveDetail>
        </wd:LeaveStatus>
        <wd:Allocation_Details 
 xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <wd:AllocationInstance>
                <wd:Costing_ID/>
                <wd:Start_Date/>
                <wd:End_Date/>
                <wd:Costing_Allocation_Data>
                    <wd:Allocation_Order/>
                    <wd:Cost_Center_Allocation/>
                    <wd:Region_Allocation/>
                    <wd:Location_Allocation/>
                    <wd:Distribution_Percentage/>
                    <wd:Default_from_Organization_Assignment/>
                </wd:Costing_Allocation_Data>
            </wd:AllocationInstance>
        </wd:Allocation_Details>
    </wd:Worker_Data>
</wd:Workers>
<wd:ChangeEventSummary>       
    <wd:ChangeEvent xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <wd:EmpID>50211</wd:EmpID>
        <wd:TermDate>2018-04-27</wd:TermDate>
        <wd:EventDetails> <!--Copied inside this node based on EmpID match-->
            <wd:LeaveStatus>
                <wd:LeaveDetail>
                    <wd:LOA_Start_Date>2017-12-22</wd:LOA_Start_Date>
                    <wd:LOA_End_Date>2018-01-22</wd:LOA_End_Date>
                </wd:LeaveDetail>
                <wd:LeaveDetail>
                    <wd:LOA_Start_Date>2018-02-20</wd:LOA_Start_Date>
                    <wd:LOA_End_Date>2018-03-02</wd:LOA_End_Date>
                </wd:LeaveDetail>
            </wd:LeaveStatus>
        </wd:EventDetails>
    </wd:ChangeEvent>
 </wd:ChangeEventSummary>
 </wd:Census_Report>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use a key: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key

Comment: Thank you Michael. I have used keys in my code and able to achieve almost what I want. But the data I want to display each leave detail as separate node. Here is the code I have built for the question.

Comment: This is now a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011601/copying-the-child-nodes-of-one-node-into-another-node-but-in-a-separate-node-ba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is the code I used to get the values:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:key name="kEmpID" match="wd:Worker_Data" 
    use="concat(ancestor::wd:LeaveStatus/wd:LeaveDetail,wd:EmpID)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:ChangeEvent/wd:EventDetails">
    <xsl:variable name="vLeaveStatus" select="key('kEmpID',../wd:EmpID)"/>
    <xsl:copy>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('kEmpID',../wd:EmpID)">
                <wd:Event>
                    <xsl:apply-templates 
    select="$vLeaveStatus/wd:LeaveStatus/*"/>
                </wd:Event>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The only problem I am getting here is all the leave details are coming under one node i.e. Event. But I want to bring each Leave details in one Event node. Can you guys help me how to get this...?